# Insert php variable in database on trigger event

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

You might say that this question already asked many time!
You right, but those dont give me solution.
I am trying to insert inserted data and two var into database using trigger on insert event, code is here:

```
< html > <body > 
<?php 

$s = $_POST['sent'];
echo "Entered sentence : $s";
$a = array();
$b = array();
if (preg_match_all('/[^=]*=([^;@]*)/', shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client '$s'"), $matches))
//if (preg_match_all('/[^=]*=([^;@]*)/', shell_exec('/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client '.escapeshellarg($s)), $matches))
{
    $a[] = (int) $matches[1][0];    //optionally cast to int
    $b[] = (int) $matches[1][1];
}

$x = (int) $matches[1][0];
$y = (int) $matches[1][1];

$p=10;
$q=20;
echo $x;
echo "<br/>";
echo $p;
echo "<br/>";


//---------------DB stuff --------------------

$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', 'root', 'test');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}


$sql2 = "CREATE TRIGGER MysqlTrigger AFTER INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO temp VALUES (NEW.sent,'".$x."','".$p."');";
mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO table1 (sent)VALUES('$_POST[sent]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql1)) {
    die('Error: '.mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($con);

?>
</html > </body >
```

Data is inserted in table1 successfuly and trigger event also works. But on trigger NEW.sent gets inserted while rest two var always inserted as "ZERO"- 0. 
Looking at various solutions given on web I tried with :

```
(NEW.sent,'$x','$p');";
(NEW.sent,"$x","$p");";
```

and other but every time it insert 0 for this two values.

Data type of $x and $p is Integer and In table I have taken int values for this two paramter. What is the issue?

Comment: If the database fields of those variables are int shouldn't you be inserting them without the single quotes?

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen: Yeah it should, but it inserts '0' for that case. I am new to PHP so not much aware about the problem here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest is:

```
(NEW.sent, ".$x.", ".$p.");";
```

Comment: This also does not work! problem is something different. When I created the trigger code in php file above then also it was working fine. Because the part that was creating trigger is Mysql trigger `DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    TRIGGER `test`.`MysqlTrigger` AFTER INSERT
    ON `test`.`table1`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 INSERT INTO temp VALUES(New.sent,'$x','$y');
    END$$

DELIMITER ;`. Here How could I retrieve '$x' and '$y'?